# Where are Adobe Acrobat DC update temporary files located?

Tags: windows-7, adobe-acrobat, temporary-files, acrobat-pro-dc

I updated Adobe Acrobat DC from version 19.10.20100.325521 to 19.12.20035.332343 on Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate, and I see that I lost 467.628032 MB in the process. Since the update seems minor, I assume that most of the lost space comes from update temporary files. The update was done through Adobe Acrobat DC -> Help -> Check for updates.

Where are Adobe Acrobat DC update temporary files located?

I unsuccessfully tried (the update was done on 2019-07-14 at around 8 PM):

- `C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Temp\`

  [image]
- `C:\Windows\Installer`

  [image]
- I searched for `AcrobatDCUpd1901220035.msp` since that the filename of the update I see on https://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/acrobatetk/tools/ReleaseNotesDC/continuous/dccontinuousmay2019qfe.html#dccontinuousmaytwentynineteenqfe  ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20190715050714/https://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/acrobatetk/tools/ReleaseNotesDC/continuous/dccontinuousmay2019qfe.html)).

Comment: What's your plan for these files once you find them?

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT remove

Answer (score 1):

The main Roaming dir in Windows 7/10 is:

> C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Roaming\Adobe\Acrobat\DC

But, After I follow Adobe Acrobat, found that in next dir with last modify files after acrobat update:

> C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Local\Temp

Still in Temp you can't found the files, since Adobe delete this files after update was complete/fail.
The extra storage you have may be clean using Windows clean tool, just type in start '*cleanmgr*'.  If after that you still finding this extra using, it probably extra files that the software need.

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is a few months old, but I had this question myself, as my FW was blocking the download of the Acrobat DC update and I had to go thru some diagnose & testing to correct my FW policies.

I found the Adobe Acrobat DC update file(s) in:

> C:\ProgramData\Adobe\ARM

Hope this helps others.